# Delphi SendMessage

Tags: delphi, windows, winapi, консоль

Добрый день. Запустил командную строку (`cmd.exe`)  и пытаюсь передать ей сообщение что клавиша `Enter` нажата, делаю вот так:

```
var
  h:HWND;
begin
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd.exe','/K', nil, SW_SHOW);
  h:=FindWindow(0,'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe');
  sendMessage(h,VK_RETURN,nil,nil);
```

Почему `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`? Да потому, что,  это имя искомого мною окна).
Но этот способ работать не хочет, возможно есть ещё варианты?

Comment: другие клавиши передаются нормально?

Comment: Нет, но всё же, интересно понять почему нет и как можно по другому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У консольных приложений нет оконного цикла, потому любой Send/PostMessage для них - пустой звук. 
Открываете потоки ввода/вывода через OpenProcess или CreateProcess, и передаете туда символ нажатия Enter.